# Adding UILabel/UIImageView to UIContentViewCell disturbs it's size

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionViewCell defined in storyboard which has a UILabel added to it's contentView. Collection view uses a flow layout and I return a fixed size  of cell in flowlayout delegate as follows:

```
 let sizeOfItem = CGFloat(210.0)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   
    return CGSize(width: sizeOfItem, height: sizeOfItem)
}
```

I added the following constraint for UILabel in storyboard and the cell automatically starts resizing itself to match the text size in UILabel. This is not what I want. I want the cell to be fixed size and label to autoshrink instead.

I even tried setting contentHuggingPriority of label to lowest value (i.e. 1). This stops the cell from auto-shrinking if the text in label is small. But still the cell grows when the text is big. I don't want this to happen either. I want the cell to be fixed size as returned by sizeForItem in delegate and the label to adapt it's font size.

EDIT: I also set contentCompressionProperty to lowest and it then works. But I am wondering what is the right way to fix this kind of scenario where contentView does not depend on subviews.

EDIT 2: The problem also appears when having UIImageView in contentView and the image is bigger or smaller than defined cell size. Setting intrinsic content size of UIImageView does not help.

[image]

Comment: I think you're not conforming right delegate, can u share more code?

Comment: The delegate is getting called, I put a breakpoint in it and it does break!

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact cell size as specified in the delegate method, you can't use an equal width constraint since then it will be a dynamic-size cell.

Comment: I have set custom size in storyboard for UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).